# Disable Y axis zooming in Plotly but redraw Y axis after X axis zoom

Tags: python, plotly

I am creating time series line charts in Plotly. When the user clicks and drags the mouse to zoom I want them to be only able to zoom in on the X axis, but I then want the Y axis to redraw so that the visible data fills the vertical space. There is an example of disabling Y axis zooming [here](https://plotly.com/python/axes/), reproduced below:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", facet_col="species")
fig.update_xaxes(fixedrange=True)
```

This does what I want in terms of only allowing the mouse action to zoom in on a time range, but then the Y axis doesn't change: its bounds on still set based on all the data that the plot has access to, not just the data that is visible.

Comment: If you run the code in the question, the x-axis will be fixed. if you want to fix the y-axis, you can use `fig.update_yaxes(...)` to change it to I am not sure I understand the intent of your question. Are you talking about unfixing the y-axis after a user operation? Why is it inconvenient to have both axes zoomable from the beginning?